# I have two tables in MySQL that have identical columns. Is there a way to detect changes between them?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, schema

I have the following tables:

**movie**

- *title* - VARCHAR (255)
- *year* - VARCHAR (4)
- *format* - VARCHAR (255)

**movie_custom**

- *title* - VARCHAR (255)
- *year* - VARCHAR (4)
- *format* - VARCHAR (255)
- username_id - INT (11)

Each table has different data, but I want to ensure that there are no changes to some of the column names. For example, if I changed *format*  - VARCHAR (255) to *distribution_type* - VARCHAR (30) on **movie**, I'd also want to make sure the same change gets made on **movie_custom**.

Is there any way to ensure this in MySQL? Somehow couple two columns together in some way?

Comment: Suggest you link to your previous question; maybe Gordon will get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

It sounds like you have a lousy data model.  If you fix the data model, you'll fix your problem.

You should have a movie database with a primary key:

```
create table movies (
    movieId int primary key auto_increment,
    . . .
);
```

Then, the second table should have three columns:

```
create table moviesCustom (
    movieCustomId int primary key auto_increment,
    movieId int not null,
    username_id int,
    constraint foreign key (movieId) references movies(movieId)
);
```

Then, when you want information in both tables, use a `join`.

Comment: The issue here is that I want users to be able to customize all data in the `movie` table, which is why I have a `movie_custom` table with all the same columns, for which a user can customize how they wish. I have no guarantee that all of the data in `movies` is correct, so `movie_custom` allows a user to store their own corrected data. If someone wants to rename a Title to `Twelve Monkeys` instead of `12 Monkeys`, then that is their choice. Are you saying I should mix user-generated data with the initial data into one single `movies` table with `username_id` being the differentiator?

Comment: @EthanAllen . . . Your comment seems diametrically opposed to the question.  The question is about keeping the values the same.  Perhaps you should ask another question about the best data structure to accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A**

For `title` create a normalization table.  Then, instead of `VARCHAR(...)`, have `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` to link to that table.

Then when adding *any* title from *anywhere* (base or custom), look up the name in that table to get the id (or create a new id).

This is probably the only way to keep the *datatype* if `title` in a single location (and appease Gordon).

However, excessive use of this (ie, multiple columns done this way) will cost something in performance.

Suggestion:  Change `year VARCHAR(4)` to `year YEAR`, since there is such a datatype.

**Plan B**

Combine the two tables; use a special `username` (perhaps NULL) as the 'base' entry.